# Why shipping methods not updated on changing of checkout fields?

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-methods, knockoutjs

In the past when I fill one of the checkout fields then shipping method section under the checkout page refreshed and then updated like this:

[image: Magento 2 shipping methods not updated]

But now shipping method not updated by calling **ajax** (or **knockoutjs** I don't know) anymore and I should refresh the page to update the shipping method section (It's based on the country field in checkout)

Comment: Is there any browser console error?

Comment: Please inspect Element one of the AJAX has issue & Check the error logs as well & post that

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh there is no error in browser console

Answer (score 0):

That was because of the fake zip code that I used for zipping/postal code filed, when you use fake zip/postal code Magento show a notice but not error so when is change zip/postal code as optional filed, and leave it blank, shipping method section refreshed and shipping methods updated

Comment: Ali, this didn't help me. Any other possible solution?